# Why SQL error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, in-operator

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT person_name
  FROM travel_card
 WHERE id IN
       (SELECT travel_card_id
          FROM travel_payment
         WHERE entry_station_id IN
               (SELECT id
                  FROM station
                 WHERE name = 'Marina Bay MRT Station'
                    OR exit_station_id IN
                       (SELECT id
                          FROM station
                         WHERE name = 'Marina Bay MRT Station'))) I
 ORDER BY travel_card.person_name
```

Why do I get this error?

> SQL ERROR: *from station where name='Marina Bay MRT Station')I)*
> ERROR at line 4: **ORA-00907**: *missing right parenthesis*

Comment: The error message refers to `)I)`, but that does not appear in your SQL. Please check that the query in your question is in fact the query you're executing. Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting your code is the first step to being able to read it and find bugs, and it's clear there are some bugs.

I think this is what you meant to write:

```
select person_name
from travel_card
where id in (
    select travel_card_id
    from travel_payment
    where entry_station_id = (
        select id
        from station
        where name = 'Marina Bay MRT Station')
    or exit_station_id = (
        select id
        from station
        where name = 'Marina Bay MRT Station')
)
order by travel_card.person_name
```

Notice that `=` replaced `in` for the station lookups and I un-nested the subqueries.

You could (and should) express this using only joins, but I left the structure as similar to your query so the differences were minimised.

Comment: Curious, why did you replace OP's `=` with `in`? Asking for future readers.

Comment: @Parfait other way around: I replaced OP's `in` with `=`. Why? Because station names are obviously unique so there can be only one row returned and further using `=` makes the query easier to understand. With `in` readers will assume there can be multiple rows returned from the subquery which in turn makes the whole query harder to grasp; with `=` it reads as *where either the entry or exit station **is** Marina Bay*.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery following an **IN** operator cannot be aliased, otherwise you'd get

- **`ORA-00907`** if the alias is nested in parentheses
  -> **`))I)`**
- **`ORA-00933`** if the alias follows all of the parentheses
  -> **`)))I`**

considering your current case.

Seems that need to tidy up the query and presumably you want to write it as the following :

```sql
SELECT person_name
  FROM travel_card
 WHERE id IN
       (SELECT travel_card_id
          FROM travel_payment tp
          JOIN station s
            ON s.id IN (tp.entry_station_id,tp.exit_station_id)
         WHERE s.name = 'Marina Bay MRT Station')
 ORDER BY person_name;
```

yet, might be shorter :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT tc.person_name
  FROM travel_payment tp
  JOIN station s
    ON s.id IN (tp.entry_station_id, tp.exit_station_id)
  JOIN travel_card tc
    ON tc.person_name = tp.travel_card_id
 WHERE s.name = 'Marina Bay MRT Station'
 ORDER BY tc.person_name
```